# how to get string from second set of brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

> services[custom][mainData]

How can I get the string `mainData`?

I have tried:

```
var result = id.match('\[(.*?)\]');
alert(result[1]);

var result = id.match(\[(.*?)\]);
alert(result[1]);
```

To no avail. its simple for me to do with one set of brackets, the 2nd set is what throws me off.

Comment: Are the strings always in that format?

Comment: If it's always the last you want, simply `/\[([^\]]*)\]$/` should do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

If the strings are always in that format, you wouldn't really need a complicated regex, you can just split on the `][` and take the remaining string without the last `]`. Something like:

```
id.split('][').pop().slice(0, -1);
```

Here's the code with comments for each step:

```js
var id = 'services[custom][mainData]';

var result = id.split('][')  // split on `][` gives [ 'services[custom', 'mainData]' ]
  .pop()                     // take the last match gives 'mainData]'
  .slice(0, -1);             // trim the last char gives 'mainData'

console.log(result);         // logs 'mainData'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a greedy `.*` before matching `[` and `]` to make sure you are always matching last `[...]`:

```js
var str = 'services[custom][mainData]';
var result = str.match(/.*\[([^\]\[]*)\]/)[1];

console.log(result); //mainData
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT4dH8/1)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to extract the second pair of brackets, just match the first pair of brackets as well.

```
var result = id.match(/\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]/);
```

With your example of `id` being `services[custom][mainData]`, `result[1]` will now be `custom` and `result[2]` will be `mainData`.

Answer (score 0):

This [regex](https://regex101.com/r/oN7aD3/1) should do it for you, as long as you catch the right group!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var test = "services[custom][mainData]";
var re   = /\[(\w+)\]\[(\w+)\]/g;
var res  = re.exec(test);
document.write(res[2]);
```